# If $a_1\le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n$ and $a_1 + 2a_2 + \cdots + na_n = 0$, then $a_1[x] + a_2[2x] + \cdots + a_n[nx] \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider a positive integer $n$ and the real numbers $a_1 \leqslant a_2 \leqslant \cdots \leqslant a_n$  such that

$\displaystyle  a_1 + 2a_2 + \cdots + na_n = 0$

Prove that

$\displaystyle  a_1[x] + a_2[2x] + \cdots + a_n[nx] \geqslant 0$

for every $x$, where $[t]$ is  the integer part of $t$

My attempt

Consider $M=\left \{ 1,2,...,n \right \}$ and $Y=\left \{ k\in M|a_k\geq 0 \right \},X=\left \{ k\in M|a_k<0 \right \}$
$\forall x\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow k[x]\leq [kx]\leq kx$

$\forall k\in Y \Rightarrow k[x]a_k\leq [kx]a_k$

$\forall k\in X\Rightarrow kxa_k\leq [kx]a_k$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{X} k[x]a_k+\sum_{Y}kxa_k\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k[kx]$

$\sum_{X} k[x]a_k+\sum_{Y}kxa_k=\sum_{X}a_k([x]-x)\geq 0$

So $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k[kx] \geq 0$

Is there a mistake in the above solution

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: Thaks for your feedback.

Comment: Please, use $\left\lfloor\,\,\,\right\rfloor$ for the $\texttt{Integer Part}$. For instance,  the $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ code is $\texttt{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}$